# Inexplicable "NoAnnotationError" on Upgrade to Angular 4

Tags: angularjs, angular

Everything was good in Angular 2. However, I upgraded to the beta release of 4 and get a NoAnnotationError on startup. I  have no services, no injectables yet.

Here's my code:

app.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.component.ts

```
require('./sass/index');

import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div class="app">
     The Angular app has now loaded!
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>`

})

export class AppComponent {
  error: any;
  showNgFor = false; 
  constructor ()
  {

  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }          from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }     from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule }        from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule }      from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }      from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
      BrowserModule, 
      HttpModule, 
      RouterModule.forRoot([]) 
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It's pretty straightforward stuff... Not sure what I possibly could have failed to annotate here.

And here's the full error:

```
Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Parser'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Parser' is decorated with Injectable.
```

Comment: Take a look at the Documentation..., ups there is none for Angular4. =)

Comment: Taking a guess here... when you moved to NG4, did you update all the other things it depends on in your package.json? Like, the latest version of TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very stupid. I was using a beta version of Angular 4. Not one of the release candidates. Upgrading to rc2 fixed it.